# Сохранить параметры activity

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сохранить состояние активити в частности значение переменной A, с помощью `onSaveInstanceState` так чтобы при следующем её запуске А сохранила выбранное значение. Делаю примерно так - значение остаётся нулевым: Возможно не совсем понимаю работу `onSaveInstanceState` - только начал учиться програмить.

```
public class ThreeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    int A = 0;
    ImageView bnt3

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            A = savedInstanceState.getInt("A");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ThreeActivity.this, A, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        btn4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        View.OnClickListener Lisen3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                A = 1;   
            }
        };
        btn3.setOnClickListener(Lisen3);
    }
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("A",A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Восстанавливать значения нужно в методе:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);
    //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: `Восстанавливать значения нужно в методе` – вовсе необязательно, it depends. Сохраненный `Bundle` приходит как в `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`, так и в `onCreate(...)`.

Comment: пробовал и в onRestoreInstanceState значение не сохраняется

Comment: А что вы называете *следующим запуском* `Activity`?

Comment: Дело в том, что `onSaveInstanceState()` вызывается не всегда, например при нажатии клавиши *back* этот метод не вызовется :)

Comment: из другой Activity по нажатию на кнопку выполняется код :Intent intent = new Intent(FourActivity.this,ThreeActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent)

Comment: Поставьте логи на save и restore и посмотрите отрабатывают они или нет

Comment: ставил - сейв отрабатывает а рестор нет

Comment: Кстати если при нажатии кнопки back метод не срабатывает - есть какая нибуть альтернатива для сохранения данных?

Comment: Как справедливо заметил @post_zeew `Bundle` с сохраненными данными приходит и в `onCreate()` и в `onRestoreInstanceState()` - в `onCreate()` он у вас тоже `null`?

Comment: угу в  onCreate тоже null

Comment: Ну тогда сливайте воду и сохраняйте свои переменные через `SharedPreferences` - некрасиво, но работает

Comment: как раз так сейчас пробую реализовать ;) - правда есть одно сомнение - после полного выхода из приложения параметры сохраняться ?

Comment: Да, сохранятся - преференсы сохраняются в файле `data/data/[package]/shared_prefs/*.xml`

Comment: Придётся придумать как их обнулять.. а в случае с onSaveInstanceState - данные сохраняются пока приложение "живёт"? (Для саморазвития :))

Answer (score 3):

Значение переменной `A` успешно сохраняется, однако при выводе `Toast` Вы получите исключение.

Метод `Toast.makeText(...)` является перегруженным и, в частности, имеет такую сигнатуру:

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration)
```

Так как все параметры совпадают по типу с передаваемыми Вами, то вызывается именно этот метод, вторым параметром которого является идентификатор текстового ресурса, значение которого необходимо отобразить в `Toast`. Так как идентификатору `1` не соответствует ни один ресурс, то при вызове `Toast.makeText(...)` Вы получаете исключение:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

Чтобы отобразить значение переменной `A`, необходимо привести его к типу `String`:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(A), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

В этом случае вызовется метод:

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, @Duration int duration)
```

который и отобразит значение переменной `A`.

---

PS. Советую почитать что-нибудь базовое по ООП и Java, так как модификаторы доступа и именование переменных у Вас хромают.

Comment: Спасибо за советы и замечания - однако сохранение значения не происходит.

Comment: @Light, С чего Вы взяли, что сохранение значения не происходит?

Comment: Возможно сохранение происходит - но не востанавливается -пробовал в блок if (savedInstanceState != null) { } вставить какой нибуть "маркер" типа тоста с сообщением - не вызывается,  savedInstanceState остаётся пустым

Comment: @Light, А между какими событиями Вы хотите сохранить состояние активити? Ну там, например, кнопку back нажимаете, а потом возвращаетесь к приложению? Или кнопку home? Или как?

Comment: сохранение происходит при переходе на другую activity (пробовал прикрутить логи вроде сохраняет :) ) а вот при переходе из другой activity на данную - не восстанавливает. Переход осущевтсляется путём:           Intent intent = new Intent(FourActivity.this,ThreeActivity.class ); startActivity(intent)